# Bad Starter?? 2000 Pontiac Sunfire

Tags: starting, pontiac, sunfire

car wont start. not even a sound. dashboard lights, over head lights, radio all come on. battery has been tested. cables all clean. cant even jump start it.

Comment: Did you check your fuses?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Manual or automatic transmission?  (Foot on clutch/brake, car in park/neutral, etc.?)

Comment: it is automatic

Comment: Fuses and cables checked? Pay special attention to the motor grounding wire, these can get damaged through the vibrations over time.